# Assembly to C Code jumps

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I'm very new to this, but I'm trying to reverse engineer assembly code to figure out what it's doing in C. The function I was looking at called a different function (func4) and I dissembled it to look. I'd appreciate any help or advice on whether I'm going in the right direction.

In the original function, 0xe was in %edx, 0 was in %esi, and a value (let's call it x) that I'm trying to discover was in %edi.

func4

```
  0x00000000004010ff <+0>:  push   %rbx
  0x0000000000401100 <+1>:  mov    %edx,%eax
```

So now %eax has 0xe.

```
  0x0000000000401102 <+3>:  sub    %esi,%eax
```

%eax = 0xe - 0

```
  0x0000000000401104 <+5>:  mov    %eax,%ebx    
  0x0000000000401106 <+7>:  shr    $0x1f,%ebx
```

%ebx = %ebx >> 0x1f = 0

```
  0x0000000000401109 <+10>: add    %ebx,%eax
```

%eax =  %eax + %ebx = 0xe

```
  0x000000000040110b <+12>: sar    %eax
```

I believe this is shorthand for sar    %eax,1, which would be 7.

```
  0x000000000040110d <+14>: lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ebx
```

Now, I think (%rax,%rsi,1) means %rax + %rsi*1, which is 7

```
  0x0000000000401110 <+17>: cmp    %edi,%ebx
  0x0000000000401112 <+19>: jle    0x401120 <func4+33>
```

This means we jump to func4+33 if ebx <= edi (if 7 <= x) Since I have no idea what x is, let's assume it's greater than 7 and not jump.

```
  0x0000000000401114 <+21>: lea    -0x1(%rbx),%edx      
  0x0000000000401117 <+24>: callq  0x4010ff <func4>
```

Here's where I'm confused. Am I going through the function again? Just with different values in the registers?

```
  0x000000000040111c <+29>: add    %eax,%ebx
  0x000000000040111e <+31>: jmp    0x40112e <func4+47>
  0x0000000000401120 <+33>: cmp    %edi,%ebx    
  0x0000000000401122 <+35>: jge    0x40112e <func4+47>
  0x0000000000401124 <+37>: lea    0x1(%rbx),%esi       
  0x0000000000401127 <+40>: callq  0x4010ff <func4>
  0x000000000040112c <+45>: add    %eax,%ebx
  0x000000000040112e <+47>: mov    %ebx,%eax    
  0x0000000000401130 <+49>: pop    %rbx
  0x0000000000401131 <+50>: retq
```

Comment: Could you post the thing in Intel syntax as well? And yes it's recursive

Comment: Did you already check if there are relocations in the program? A relocation at the "callq" would mean that another function is called!

Comment: I think it's recursive function written completely in assembly so it's use registers with his rules. can you post disassembly of your program ?

Comment: Can anyone enlighten me about this "dialect"? His second instruction 'mov    %edx,%eax ', when I use my VC2008 disassembly, would mean to move eax to edx, but here it seems to mean to move edx to eax, i.e. operands are reversed???

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I think you disassemble with intel syntax and his source in AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to evaluate *func4* right away. First translate it to C by translating each line of assembly one by one. The result should look like this:

```
int func4 (int edi, int esi, int edx)
{
    // temporaries
    int eax, ebx;

    eax = edx;
    eax = eax - esi;
    ebx = eax;
    ebx = (unsigned int)ebx >> 31;
    eax = eax + ebx;
    eax = eax >> 1;
    ebx = eax + esi + 1;
    if (ebx <= edi) goto L1;
    edx = ebx - 1;
    eax = func4 (edi, esi, edx);
    ebx = ebx + eax;
    goto L2;
L1:
    if (ebx >= edi) goto L2;
    esi = ebx + 1;
    eax = func4 (edi, esi, edx);
    ebx = ebx + eax;
L2:
    eax = ebx;
    return eax;
}
```

It is ugly, but it works.

Now, as I understand, given a *y*, you are looking for an *x* such that `y = func4 (x, 0, 14);`

You have two options:

1. Rewrite *func4* so that it becomes understandable enough for you to figure out what it does and guess which *x* you have to pass to get the given *y*.
2. Calculate `y = func4 (x, 0, 14)` for all values of *x* until you get the desired *y*.

Comment: Note that `sar %eax` is not the same as `eax = eax/2`, when eax is negative, as the shift will round down (towards -infinity), while the divide will round towards 0.   In fact the whole "shift by 31" stuff with ebx is the compiler's fixup for this difference, so those 4 instructions should be replaced with just `eax = eax/2`